# Add form to layout

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I need to add a login popup to the header of every page, so naturally I want to add it to the layout as a partial view.

The problem is, the layout doesnt have a pagemodel.

We do use a BasePageModel that every page inherits from, where I can add 2 strings for username/password. But how would the layout see those fields?

Comment: You can use bootstrap modal as popup and load the partial login view dynamically on the bootstrap modal.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a model for the Layout page just as you would a standard content page:

```
@model BasePageModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
```

Then your properties are accessible via the `Model` property of the Layout page. The `BasePageModel` will also be passed to any partials that you add to the layout (unless you specify a different model for the partial), so you can also access the properties in those.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to add a login popup to the header of every page, so naturally
> I want to add it to the layout as a partial view.

According to your description, I do a demo for that situation. But I don’t use a BasePageModel that every page inherits from.

The  demo as below, hoping it can help you.

1.Add a Login page with page model, and post method

Login.cshtml.cs:

```
 public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
      
        [BindProperty]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Msg { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost(string Username, string Password)
        {
           //do your other things...
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

Login.cshtml:

```
@page
@model Login.Pages.LoginModel
@{
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Login Form</h3>
    @Model.Msg
    <form method="post" asp-page="Login">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" asp-for="@Model.Password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Add the login form in the layout. Using name attribute: change ***input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Username"***  into ***input type="text" name="Username"***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                   </div>
                        <div>

                            <fieldset>

                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">

                                            <button id="btnShowModal" type="button"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-default pull-left col-lg-11 button button4">
                                                login
                                            </button>

                                            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal"
                                                 data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
                                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                ×
                                                            </button>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                            <form method="post" asp-page="Login">
                                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>Username</td>
                                                                        <td><input type="text" name="Username"></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>Password</td>
                                                                        <td><input type="password" name="Password"></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                                                        <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </table>
                                                            </form>

                                                        </div>

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>

                </div>
        </nav>
       
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - Login - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnShowModal").click(function () {
                $("#loginModal").modal('show');
            });

            $("#btnHideModal").click(function () {
                $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Results:

[image]

[image]